# exec() text redirection for PHP on Windows on SVN post-commit hook

Tags: php, svn, exec, post-commit, mantis

I have been following the post below trying to hook my SubVersion installation to my Mantis bug tracker.

[How To Integrate Subversion and Mantis](http://blog.bonetree.net/2008/09/how-to-integrate-subversion-and-mantis/)

Everything works fine until the last line where it calls the Mantis checkin.php script and feeds it the message string that has been created in the script.

```
exec(CHECKIN . " <<< \"$message\"");
```

I understand the purpose of the line is to send the message string to **STDIN** which Mantis' **checkin.php** reads in order to check for an appropriate matching string and update the Mantis tracking database.

Anyways, I know the above convention is for a Linux installation. My question is how would I use the PHP **exec()** function in a Windows environment to call the PHP script(checkin.php) and pass the string built in this program to **STDIN**.

**NOTE:** I would prefer not to change the logic in checkin.php to read from STDIN.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gotten any more posts, but after toying with the system() function, I was able to redirect a file as input to STDIN but was unable to pass a string of data. I had the option of doing something similar to a batch job in my PHP where I would write a temp file, and use that as input to STDIN, but since I was already using a batch file for the post-commit hook in SVN to call the PHP script I figured I would go ahead and just write the entire script there in the batch file.

Here is my final solution for the SVN post-commit hook:

**post-commit.bat**

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL

SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2

SET PHP="C:\Program Files\PHP\php.exe"
SET CHECKIN="D:\mantisbt-1.1.8\core\checkin.php"
SET SVNLOOK="C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svnlook.exe"

SET LOGFILE=log%REV%.txt
SET AUTHORFILE=author%REV%.txt
SET OUTPUTFILE=output%REV%.txt
SET CHANGEFILE=change%REV%.txt

ECHO Author: > %AUTHORFILE%
%SVNLOOK% author -r %REV% %REPOS% >> %AUTHORFILE%

ECHO Log: > %LOGFILE%
%SVNLOOK% log -r %REV% %REPOS% >> %LOGFILE%

ECHO Files: > %CHANGEFILE%
%SVNLOOK% changed %REPOS% %REV% >> %CHANGEFILE%

ECHO Revision: %REV% > %OUTPUTFILE%
%SVNLOOK% date %REPOS% -r %REV% >>  %OUTPUTFILE%
TYPE %AUTHORFILE% >> %OUTPUTFILE%
TYPE %LOGFILE% >> %OUTPUTFILE%
TYPE %CHANGEFILE% >> %OUTPUTFILE%

TYPE %OUTPUTFILE% | %PHP% %CHECKIN% 

CALL DEL %LOGFILE%
CALL DEL %AUTHORFILE%
CALL DEL %CHANGEFILE%
CALL DEL %OUTPUTFILE%
```

This script updates a matching mantis ticket with a comment in the following format:

> ```
> Revision: 41
> 2009-11-25 11:47:18 -1000 (Wed, 25 Nov 2009)
> Author: 
> jason
> Log: 
> Testing for checkin for TER #12345 which fixes Mantis issue 0000001.
> Files:
> U TANDEM/CAB/CABLONGD
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Redirects using the < and > are processed by the shell—on windows by cmd.exe.  The easiest way to get that functionality is with [`system()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).  `exec()` does not use a shell:  to use it, you'd have to orchestrate the redirection before calling exec.

Comment: @wallyk - +1 for the helpful tip. still not quite there, but that does put me in the right direction thanks! I can pass a file in now, but still can't figure out how to pass a string in.